# ASP.NET - How can I check how many milliseconds my codes takes to execute, using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to check how long a particular segment of code takes to execute,
just want to see if some loops etc. can be optimized better or use LinQ.

Is there such function built into Visual Studio or must I do this with some
code, stopwatch class etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have VS2010 Ultimate:

From the `Analyze` menu, select the `Launch Performance Wizard` option.

Its been a while since I last used it, but I believe it tells you how long things take to execute and what's using up the most memory, and so on =)

Otherwise, you'll have to use the `Stopwatch` class or a third party profiler.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// you code.

sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Or you can use built in VS Profiler.  You can find more on how to use VS profiler in [Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Premium/Ultimate/Team versions come with a profiler. Otherwise you have to do your own profiling with the `StopWatch` class.

Comment: Its not availible in the Professional version? That sucks =(

Comment: No, it isn't. And yes it does.